# Kruskal algorithm code crushes for unknown reason

Tags: c++, cout

I have tried hard before coming here and did my research. The code below crushes and I suspect a misuse of **cout**. (This is not supposed to be the most optimal implementation there is but that is not the pb for the time being)

Could anyone with experience see where the problem is?

Many thanks in advance

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream> //file io
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
  string NumberToString ( T Number )
  {
     ostringstream ss;
     ss << Number;
     return ss.str();
  }

class Point { //an instance of this class represents the integer triples: (i, j, cost).

    int Edge1, Edge2, Cost;

    public:
    Point(int x, int y, int z) : Edge1(x), Edge2(y), Cost(z) {}
    Point() {Edge1=Edge2=Cost=0;}

    bool operator<(Point const &other) {
        return (Cost < other.Cost);
    }


    void setEdge1(int x){this->Edge1=x;}
    void setEdge2(int x){this->Edge2=x;}
    void setCost(int x){this->Cost=x;}
    int getEdge1(){return this->Edge1;}
    int getEdge2(){return this->Edge2;}
    int getCost(){return this->Cost;}

};

class GRAPH
{
    private:
    vector<Point> GraphMatrix;
    int GRAPH_vertex=0;
    int initialised=0;

public:

    GRAPH(string Path)
    {

    this->initialised=1;
     // import input data from file
    vector<int> reader(10);
    ifstream ifp(Path, ios::in);
    int ii = 0;
    while(!ifp.eof() )
    {
    ifp >> reader[ii++];
    if (ii%9 ==0)
    reader.resize(reader.size() +10);
    }
    reader.resize(ii-1);

    //End of data import


    this->GRAPH_vertex=reader[0];// Number of vertices set

    for(int i=0;i<(ii-2)/3;i++)
    {
        Point punto(reader[1+3*i],reader[2+3*i],reader[3+3*i]);

        GraphMatrix.insert(GraphMatrix.end(),punto);
    }

    }


    //Copy constructor omited

    ~GRAPH() //destructor
    {
        if (this != NULL)
        delete this;
    }


    int Get_GRAPH_vertex(){return GRAPH_vertex;}
    vector<Point> Get_GraphMatrix() {return GraphMatrix;}

    void Kruskal();
    friend bool compareTwoPoint(Point,Point);
};

bool compareTwoPoint(Point rowA, Point rowB){
     return ( rowA.getCost()<rowB.getCost() );
 }

void GRAPH::Kruskal()
{
    int n_vertices=this->GRAPH_vertex;
    std::sort(GraphMatrix.begin(),GraphMatrix.end(),&compareTwoPoint);
    vector <int> temp1(n_vertices*n_vertices,0);
    int minimumcost=0;
    int Iteration=0;
    vector<string> Tree;
    for (std::vector<Point>::iterator it=GraphMatrix.begin(); it!=GraphMatrix.end(); ++it)
    {
        int ii=it->getEdge1();
        int jj=it->getEdge2();
        if((temp1[ii+n_vertices*jj] !=1)&& Iteration<n_vertices)
        {
            temp1[ii+n_vertices*jj]=1;
            temp1[jj+n_vertices*ii]=1;
            minimumcost+=it->getCost();
            Iteration+=1;
            Tree.push_back(NumberToString(ii)+"->"+ NumberToString(jj));
        }
    }
            cout<<Iteration<<'\n';
            cout<<"minimum cost is"+ NumberToString(minimumcost)<<'\n';


            for (vector<string>::iterator p = Tree.begin();
                p != Tree.end(); ++p)
                {
                cout << *p << '\n';
                cout << endl;
                }
}


int main()
{
    GRAPH grafe("C:/Users/Algoris/Desktop/simplon.txt");

    grafe.Kruskal();
}
```

//A sample of the txt file input

```
20
0 1 17 
0 2 2 
0 3 9 
0 4 24 
0 5 28 
0 6 29 
0 7 14 
0 8 28 
0 9 13 
0 10 23
0 11 10
0 12 15
0 13 23
0 14 15
0 15 18
0 16 11
0 17 4
0 18 27
0 19 5
```

Comment: This won't fix your algorithm but your naming scheme doesn't make sense. A point doesn't inherently have two edges, but an edge inherently has two points. I would reverse the names, so you have Class Edge which has members point1, point2 and cost. Makes much more sense.

Comment: What output are you getting? Any error messages?

Comment: You are right! sorry for this inconvenience. I admit I programmed it quickly

Comment: I get the output I expect on the terminal but windows also says that  the .exe ceased to work and asks me to close the window.

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger?

Comment: It looks like your algorithm assumes the test data is a tree. This will just loop through all the edges from least cost to highest cost without taking into account cycles or circuits. I can't tell you more without knowing where it crashed though.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. As for the algorithm it makes no assumption on the graph form I have truncated the input file that I pasted.

@smocking yes I did. I have solved the pb now; it was because of the destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you run the program under a debugger until it crashes, and then post the stack trace? This will show you where the problem lies.

One problem that leaps out is this:

```
~GRAPH() //destructor
{
    if (this != NULL)
    delete this;
}
```

The destructor is called when the object is either deleted (from the heap) or goes out of scope (on the stack).  So by this point, it is already being deleted.  The `this` pointer will be valid and non-NULL in an instance method, so this is trying to do a double `delete` on your GRAPH object.

In general, you should *not* call `delete this`.  (About the only time this is valid is if you're implementing your own memory management such as a reference counting scheme, or smart pointers.)

The destructor should free memory that is owned by the object, but not the object itself.

Comment: I would say "The destructor should free memory that is _explicitly allocated and_ owned by the object"; in this case, no memory is explicitly allocated, so the destructor (and copy constructor) should be removed.

Comment: Thank you gavinb : Problem solved. and thanks for reminding me of that crucial rule when using a destructor.

Comment: @KenY-N It is possible for an object to own memory without having allocated it itself, hence the above choice of words.

Comment: @gavinb: Yes - my wording was bad, now I review it. I was trying (but failing!) to highlight to the questioner that the implicit memory allocation of a `vector` need not be freed, but... I now seem to be confusing myself, so I'll stop.